# android studio does not import the classes and mark the errors

Tags: android, android-studio

it's very strange , it worked fine yesterday but today when I write code for android studio , it doesn't automatically import classes ,for example , I used these code it doesn't mark any errors , it doesn't import any classes  :

```
AlertDialog.Builder a = new Builder(Books.this);
                            a.setMessage( (body));
                            a.setPositiveButton( ("شروع مسابقه"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Books.this, Mosabeghe_frist.class));
                                }
                            });
                            a.setNegativeButton( ("بعدا"),  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                            AlertDialog dialog = a.show();
                            TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                            messageText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                            messageText.setTypeface(typeface);
```

I had to import all these classes by my self , it doesn't mark the errors , just when I hit the start the gradle tells me this line has problem , that class does not imported and so on .

How can I fix this problem ?

thanks

Comment: Did you try **cleaning** and **rebuilding** your project?

Comment: It should mark the errors when you rebuild the project.